Ag grid theme that matches current VSCode colors
I am wanting to use Ag-Grid in a VSCode extension to provide an editable grid in a webview as an alternative to VSCode’s data grid which sadly does not support editting.
I am using Vue for my webview.
It looks like Ag-Grid will work fine for
my purpose but I need to change the background color in the supplied theme to match the  VScode background.
I believe that the VSCode colors are exposed so it should be possible to do this.
Alternatively is there already an available Community theme that mirrors VSCode’s look and feel?
